# How can I create a doughnut chart that displays two specific values?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to display two specific values in a doughnut chart.  These two values come from another form (because they are evaluated there).  This is the code of the first part.

```
Private Sub CoursesRemainingChartToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CoursesRemainingChartToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim frmCharts As New Charts

    frmCharts.CompletedCoursesPass = CompletedCourses
    frmCharts.IncompleteCoursesPass = IncompleteCourses
    frmCharts.Show()

End Sub
```

After this values are passed, the new form to display the chart opens.

```
Public Class Charts

Public Property CompletedCoursesPass As Integer
Public Property IncompleteCoursesPass As Integer

Private Sub Charts_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Chart1.Series("CompletedCourses").Points.AddXY("Completed Courses", CompletedCoursesPass)
    Chart1.Series("IncompleteCourses").Points.AddXY("Incomplete Courses", IncompleteCoursesPass)

End Sub
End Class
```

How can I correctly display (and code) these results?   I'm stuck programming this part of my work.  Is there any example of a code that uses a doughnut chart in VB.Net?

Comment: What's the problem you are having, you didn't mention that except asking how to correctly display the results...

Comment: They are being displayed as one alone (the same color).